# ttk notebook bolder tabs

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Is there a way to make the borders around the tabs on a `ttk Notebook` bolder? The documentation for `ttk` (found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tab-options)) lists the following keywords:

- State
- Sticky
- Padding
- Text
- Image
- Compound
- Underline

Is there a way to get an argument similar to `relief` on many standard `tkinter` widgets? Here is my example code:

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Label
root = Tk ()
notebook = ttk.Notebook (root)
notebook.add (Label (notebook, text = "Page 1 content."), text = "Page 1")
notebook.add (Label (notebook, text = "Page 2 content."), text = "Page 2")
notebook.add (Label (notebook, text = "Page 3 content."), text = "Page 3")
notebook.pack ()
root.mainloop ()
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe with ttk styles?

Comment: Sadly, because this cannot be used in the `add` method, this wouldn't work.